# Multiple opening hour definitions in schema.org

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have to implement schema.org for a large local car dealer with
repair shop, gas station, showroom and car wash. All on one website.

Is it possible to define for each area own opening hours in schema.org? And maybe google show them all?
Like

`<meta itemprop="openingHours" item-name="Gas Station" content="Mo-Sa 11:00-14:30">`
or are any child-entities reserved for this use case?

Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each area needs its own item (in Microdata introduced with the `itemscope` attribute). And the opening hours for an area have to be nested under its item.

So the whole business could be an [`AutomotiveBusiness`](http://schema.org/AutomotiveBusiness). The repair shop are could be an [`AutoRepair`](http://schema.org/AutoRepair), the wash area could be an [`AutoWash`](http://schema.org/AutoWash), and so on. And to relate the areas with the business, you could use the [`department` property](http://schema.org/department).

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AutomotiveBusiness">

  <!-- properties about the whole business go here -->

  <div itemprop="department" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AutoRepair">
    <!-- properties about the repair area go here -->
  </div>

  <div itemprop="department" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AutoWash">
    <!-- properties about the wash area go here -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use schema hours to distinguish each separate entity's opening hours, but the best way to get each entity listed in Google is to have a Google My Business page for each one. 
I have clients who offer multiple services at the same location in the same manner you do. The trick is to add a "sub address" to the location by adding either a suite number or letter. i.e. 1234 Mary Way #100, or 1234 Mary Way #A.
Google Map Maker allows users to add unique addresses such as this to divide inner locations on buildings or establishments.

Hope this helps